# Temp Cube and Deployed Cube not the same

Tags: ssas

I'm still new to SSAS cubes and came across a very interesting thing. When I deploy me cube to the server and browse it and compare the results to the temp Cube that's created by default. I get different results.

Can you please explain why this is happening and the way forward.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "Temp Cube"? Are you sure that you use the same datasource? If your cube is not in direct query (or Rolap), you play maybe with different data. Do a process full of your cubes and check again.

Comment: Thanks, I did process full on both cubes and the data matched. They are using the same datasource, but the temp cube has not been processed since it was created.

Comment: Super then :) .